How to apply One Payment for Multiple Invoices
Let us say there are 5 invoices they belong to same Customer.



InvoiceID
Amount




1
200


2
400


3
300


4
500



Customer pays 1000
The payment should be applied to invoices 1, 2, 3 in full and partial (100 to invoice 4)



InvoiceID
Amount
Payment
Unpaid




1
200
200
0


2
400
400
0


3
300
300
0


4
500
100
400



Tried to loop through records but failed.
kbr = me.payment
Do Until rs.EOF
        
        
        If DLookup("closed", "invoice", "bilid=" & rs!Utility) = 0 And rs!Charges > 0 Then
        
        If kBr >= rs!Charges Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into advdep ( advbill, advdate, adv_amt, advmode, payref ) values ( " & rs!Utility & " , #" & AdvDate & "#, " & rs!Charges & " , Advmode, payref) " ': DoCmd.RunSQL "update invoice set paidamt=paidamt + " & rs!Charges & ", closed = 1 where bilid=" & rs!Utility & " and closed = 0"
        ElseIf kBr > 0 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into advdep ( advbill, advdate, adv_amt, advmode, payref ) values ( " & rs!Utility & " , #" & AdvDate & "#, " & (rs!Charges - kBr) & " , Advmode, payref) " ': DoCmd.RunSQL "update invoice set paidamt=paidamt + " & rs!Charges & ", closed = 1 where bilid=" & rs!Utility & " and closed = 0"
        Else
        Exit Do
        End If
        kBr = kBr - rs!Charges
        rs.MoveNext
    
    Loop


MS Access and MariaDB are totally different databases.  Which one are you actually using?

It is ms access front end. Mariadb is backend

@VineyKumar To confirm, you mean you're using a Linked-Data-Source in Access with MariaDB's ODBC driver?

Load the selected invoices as a sorted recordset and loop through and update the invoices until the paid amount has been consumed.

"Tried to loop through records but failed" - Please show us the loop you already wrote.

Yes, it is linked database with MS Access as front end and Mariadb as back end.

What does "failed" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Should use indentation in code to make it more readable. What should happen if payment is greater than invoices? Alternative is to apply payment to account, not invoices. Calculate balance when needed.

Consider pure SQL and avoid VBA by using a running sum window function to calculate against total payment. MariaDB supports window functions and Access can run the update query via a pass-through query referencing original database tables and not linked tables.
Please see dbfiddle demonstrating solution with assumptions on database structure, namely in customers, invoices, and payments tables.
UPDATE invoices i 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
      i.customer_id,
      i.invoice_id,
      i.amount AS invoice_amount,
      SUM(i.amount) OVER(
          PARTITION BY i.customer_id
          ORDER BY i.invoice_id
      ) AS invoice_running_sum,
      p.payment

  FROM invoices i
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        SUM(amount) AS payment
    FROM payments
    GROUP BY 
        customer_id
  ) p
    ON i.customer_id = p.customer_id 
) sub 
  ON i.invoice_id = sub.invoice_id
SET i.paid = (
  CASE 
    WHEN sub.invoice_running_sum < sub.payment
    THEN 0
    ELSE sub.invoice_running_sum - sub.payment
  END
);

online demo
